# appendTo аналогичные функции в Js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как реализовать на нативном js аналогичную функцию appendTo (jquery) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517697/appending-html-using-native-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взял пример с http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Вариант 1, с помощью `appendChild`

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inner"), function(item) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "Тест";
  item.appendChild(p);  
});
```

```html
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2, с помощью `insertAdjacentHTML`

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inner'), function(item) {
  item.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>Test</p>');
})
```

```html
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Вариант 3. Извините, тупой, даже пример приводить не буду.
Тоже самое, но с `innerHTML += ''`. Так делать нельзя

Подробнее -

```
elem.innerHTML += '123';
```

То же самое что и

```
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + "123";
```

То есть, весь DOM внутри элемента перестраивается. Если этот элемент - форма - то все введеные в input значения и их состояние будет обнулено в некоторых браузерах. Ну и явно неоптимально брать и перестраивать все ради добавления одного элемента

Comment: так выкидываю поэтом и нужен нативный js) Почему 3 вариант плохой объясните ( любопытство)

Comment: См. ответ. Отредактировал

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь буду мучаться с внутренними event

Comment: стоит обратить внимание на то, что в первом случае параметр - элемент, а во втором - текст. в jQuery же можно передавать и то и то